# node.js - Slice a byte into bits

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

How can I take an octet from the buffer and turn it into a binary sequence?
I want to decode protocol [rfc1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) through node.js but find it difficult to work with bits.

Here is a code, but it does not suit me - because it is a blackbox for me:

```
var sliceBits = function(b, off, len) {
  var s = 7 - (off + len - 1);

  b = b >>> s;
  return b & ~(0xff << len);
};
```

Comment: I found [this article](https://www.taniarascia.com/bits-bytes-bases-and-a-hex-dump-javascript/) extremely helpful with understanding how this stuff works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [bitmask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29#Querying_the_status_of_a_bit), an octet is 8 bits so you can do something like the following:

```
for (var i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
   var bit = octet & (1 << i) ? 1 : 0;
   // do something with the bit (push to an array if you want a sequence)
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3NUVq/

You could probably make this more efficient, but the approach is pretty straightforward.  This loops over an offset `i`, from 7 down to 0, and finds the `i`th bit using the bitmask `1 << i`.  If the `i`th bit is set then `bit` becomes `1`, otherwise it will be `0`.

Comment: thanks, i just copy one octet, and use you code 
tmpByte = tmpSlice.toString('ascii', 0, 1).charCodeAt(0);
var octet = tmpByte;

Comment: another alternative without the ternary operator is: for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) { var bit = octet >> 7 - i & 1; ... }

Comment: Good suggestion, I'm sure that is more efficient.